# Dto projection construction with collection string

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 2, jpa with hibernate.

I try to do a dto projection with one of my entity

```
@Entity
public class Factories extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "factories_id_seq", sequenceName = "factories_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "factories_id_seq")
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String address;

    @OneToOne
    private Cities cities;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<GranulateProducts> granulateProducts = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "factory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private final List<Machines> machines = new ArrayList<>();

    @ElementCollection
    private Collection<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();

    private boolean generatedEmail;

    private boolean generation;

    private String phone;

    private String fax;

    private String director;

    ...
}
```

My dto

```
public class FactoriesEditDto {

    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String address;

    private Integer citiesId;
    private String citiesName;

    private List<Integer> machinesId = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();

    private boolean generatedEmail;

    private boolean generation;

    private String phone;

    private String fax;

    private String director;

    public FactoriesEditDto(Integer id, String name, String address, Cities cities, List<Machines> machines, Collection<String> emails, boolean generatedEmail, boolean generation, String phone, String fax, String director) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;

        if (cities != null) {
            this.citiesId = cities.getId();
            this.citiesName = cities.getName();
        }

        machines.stream().forEach(machine -> machinesId.add(machine.getId()));

        this.emails = (List<String>) emails;
        this.generatedEmail = generatedEmail;
        this.generation = generation;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.fax = fax;
        this.director = director;
    }

    ...
}   


public interface FactoriesRepository extends JpaRepository<Factories, Integer> {

public FactoriesEditDto findDtoedById(Integer id);
```

}

When I run and try to do conversion, I get

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate
>   appropriate constructor on class [com.lcm.dto.FactoriesEditDto]. 
>   Expected arguments are:  int,  java.lang.String,  java.lang.String, 
>   com.lcm.model.Cities,  com.lcm.model.Machines,  java.lang.String, 
>   boolean,  boolean,  java.lang.String,  java.lang.String, 
>   java.lang.String [
>
> select    new com.lcm.dto.FactoriesEditDto    (   generatedAlias0.id, 
>     generatedAlias0.name,   generatedAlias0.address, 
>     generatedAlias0.cities,     machines,   emails, 
>     generatedAlias0.generatedEmail,     generatedAlias0.generation, 
>     generatedAlias0.phone,      generatedAlias0.fax, 
>     generatedAlias0.director    )  from com.lcm.model.Factories as
>   generatedAlias0   left join generatedAlias0.machines as machines 
>     left join generatedAlias0.emails as emails where
>   generatedAlias0.id=:param0
>
> ]

Look like, emails is see like a string instead of Collection of string...

Comment: As the JPA spec tells you, you cannot **select** a **multi**-valued field. And a Collection is ?

Comment: ok so will need to forget dto projection... and to all manually...